# React Native rotateY results in blurry text

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a flip card component in React Native for iOS devices, and this is how I approached it:

```
<Animated.View ref="container" style={{position:'relative',transform:[{rotateY:'0deg'}]}}>
    <View ref="frontFace"><Text>Front face</Text></View>
    <View ref="backFace" style={{transform:[{rotateY:'-180deg'}]}}><Text>Back face</Text></View>
</Animated.View>
```

1. overlap two Views using absolute position in side a container View
2. flip the back face using rotateY:'-180deg'
3. when the flip button is tapped, flip the container using Animated component by interpolating rotateY of the container from '0deg' to '180deg'

Sorry about the over-simplified code above - this code works fine and smoothly too. The problem is that the back face is blurry in the simulator, and ugly pixelated on a device.

Is there a way to fix this? Or any better suggestion on how to implement a flip card component?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Okay, solved it by pulling the back face out of the container and rotate it simultaneously to avoid nested transformation. But this seems a bit troublesome - I'm wondering if there is a way to control the quality of rendering.

Comment: I'm having exactly same issue. Any tips?

Answer (score 4):

Replace 

`transform: [{ rotateY: '-180deg'}]`

 style with: 

`transform : [{scaleX: -1}]`
 
resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

In my web page, also has blurry text problem,

`transform: scaleX(-1);`

fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
transform: [{
    skewY: '-180deg'
}],
```

instead of

```
transform: [{
    rotateY: '-180deg'
}],
```

on your backFace View. For me that's working like a charm on iOS and Android.